# Iterator in std::set containing std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, set

How can I can gain access to a `map` which is stored in `std::set`? I need to do something like

```
for (iterator=map.begin(); iterator!=map.end(); iterator++) {
    some_function(iterator->first);
}
```

, but instead of map im using set containing maps.

Comment: What do you know about the map you want to search?

Comment: Be aware that `std::set::iterator` is `std::set::const_iterator` in C++11.

Comment: Exactly like that, only first you have to find your map in your set.

Comment: Key value of map is struct containing two integers, and the mapped value is int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very different from iterating any other map.

```
set<map<int, int> > s;
for (set<map<int, int> >::iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it) {
  for (map<int, int>::iterator iter = it->begin(); iter != it->end(); ++iter) {
     .. do something ...
  }
}
```

So first you iterate over the set and then over the elements of the map pointed to by the outer container's iterator. I have used `map<int, int>` here just for illustration.

Comment: @stardust_ [both versions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/begin/) are available. Even the example on that page shows usage with non-const iterator

Comment: Shouldn't it be `map<int, int>::const_iterator iter = it->begin()` ? begin() returns const_iterator for set.

Comment: Thanks, i must be really tired to not realize this.

Answer (score 1):

Using range-for makes this much simpler (assuming I understand your question):

```
for (map<int, int>& m : my_set) {
    some_function(m);
}
```